# What's the difference between Helvetica.dfont and HelveticaNeue.dfont?

Tags: macos, truetype

> ## I'm not asking what the differences are between Helvetica and Helvetica Neue.

My problem arises from the fact that when I try to use `CTFrameDraw` to render fonts, almost all of them work. However, notably, Helvetica Neue works but Helvetica doesn't. (Similarly, Courier New works but Courier doesn't, yet that might be unrelated since Courier is `.ttf` and Courier New is `.dfont`.)

For the life of me I can't find what the essential difference is; they both seem to be encoded the same or similarly. So, does anyone know: **What major difference exists between `Helvetica.dfont` and `HelveticaNeue.dfont` that would let Neue be drawn just fine, but not Helvetica?**

This is in Mac OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan), where `Helvetica.dfont` is version `10.0d4e1` and `HelveticaNeue.dfont` is version `10.0d40e1`.

---

### Update 1

I've narrowed the problem down to this: When I call `CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString`, the resulting frame has `1` line for most fonts, but `0` for Helvetica and Courier.

---

### Update 2

I've discovered that, for Helvetica and Courier, the bounding rect returned by [`NSAttributedString.boundingRect(with:options:context)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1529154-boundingrectwithsize) is slightly too short, and by adding `9` (no idea why `9`), the bounding rect becomes just tall enough to allow `CTFramesetterCreateFrame` to see that the text can be drawn (as the documentation says, *"The framesetter  will continue to fill the frame until it either runs out of text or it finds that text no longer fits."*, so give it a big enough frame and it will draw all the text).

Now the question is: **Why isn't [`NSAttributedString.boundingRect(with:options:context)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1529154-boundingrectwithsize) returning the proper bounding rect for these two old fonts?**

---

If you must see my render code, it's right here:https://gist.github.com/BenLeggiero/41d244f6c620d6358ced9d2811986945

Here's a screenshot from a playground in which I'm testing it out:

[image: An attempt to render four fonts: Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Courier, and Courier New. Only Helvetica Neue and Courier New rendered.]

<sup>where `previewFontImage` just calls `renderToImage` using the given font name as the string, and generating a font of that name at size 50, and returns the image result as an `NSImage`.</sup>